# Redundant Internet access with Cisco IOS 15.x and SLA tracking

Tags: cisco

Folks,

I'm trying to get SLA tracking working on a router with two broadband Internet connections, NAT and SLA tracking.

This is something I've done many times with IOS 12.x, and is relatively straightforward.

The problem I'm facing is that this particular customer router (a Cisco 1921) runs IOS 15.1 and the previous syntax (ip sla xx) is no longer valid. Instead, it is replaced with Cisco's new approach of setting up servers and responders.

Just so this makes sense, here's a snip from a configuration I have working on an IOS 12.x, tracking across two FE interfaces connected to the respective ISP broadband router:

```
----
track 1 rtr 1 reachability
  delay down 15 up 10

track 2 rtr 2 reachability
  delay down 15 up 10

ip sla 1
  icmp-echo 10.10.10.1 source-interface Fastethernet0/0
  timeout 1000
  threshold 40
  frequency 3

ip sla 2
  icmp-echo 10.10.20.1 source-interface Fastethernet0/1
  timeout 1000
  threshold 40
  frequency 3

route-map nat-1 permit 10
  match ip address 100
  match interface FastEthernet0/0

route-map nat-2 permit 10
  match ip address 100
  match interface FastEthernet0/1

ip sla schedule 1 life forever start-time now
ip sla schedule 2 life forever start-time now

access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.108.0 0.0.0.255 any

ip nat inside source route-map nat-1 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload
ip nat inside source route-map nat-2 interface FastEthernet0/1 overload

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FastEthernet0/0 track 1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FastEthernet0/1 track 2
----
```

The above syntax is all out of the window for IOS 15.x and SLAs engine 3.0.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Here's an extract of the show ver:

```
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2011 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Tue 06-Dec-11 16:02 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M15, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
<SNIP>
Cisco CISCO1921/K9 (revision 1.0) with 487424K/36864K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FGL1615213P
<SNIP>
Cisco CISCO1921/K9 (revision 1.0) with 487424K/36864K bytes of memory.
  Processor board ID FGL1615213P
  1 DSL controller
  1 Ethernet interface
  2 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
  1 ATM interface
  1 terminal line

DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity disabled.
255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
245744K bytes of USB Flash usbflash0 (Read/Write)


License Info:

License UDI:

-------------------------------------------------
Device#   PID           SN
-------------------------------------------------
*0        CISCO1921/K9          FGL1615213P

Technology Package License Information for Module:'c1900'

-----------------------------------------------------------------
Technology    Technology-package           Technology-package
Current       Type           Next reboot
------------------------------------------------------------------
ipbase        ipbasek9      Permanent      ipbasek9
security      None          None           None
data          None          None           None
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Network Engineering. With the new version 15 software train, a data license is needed for IP SLA on Cisco 1921 routers. Please include `show version` of the router for us to see, what licenses you have installed. The base license only includes IP SLA responder. More information: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/cloud-systems-management/software-activation-on-integrated-services-routers-isr/white_paper_c11_556985.html

Comment: Thanks @Cown.  Just updated the post with the output of show ver.  Seems there is no data license.  If I was to purchase a data license, would I be able to again start using the old IOS ip sla syntax or has this changed?
Thanks again.

Comment: If you buy the data license, your config will work again, just as version 12.

Comment: Thanks very much. Time to try and seek a local Cisco partner who can source this at reasonable cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new version 15 software train, a data license is needed for IP SLA on Cisco 1921 routers. Please include show version of the router for us to see, what licenses you have installed. The base license only includes IP SLA responder.

After licenses upgrade you can use the commands/configuration you've specified above.

More information: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/cloud-systems-management/software-activation-on-integrated-services-routers-isr/white_paper_c11_556985.html